# Aberth–Ehrlich method GPU implementation

Tags: c++, gpgpu, vulkan

My current implementation is not stable and/or correct. The result may vary from one run to another.
I only want to solve 5th degree polynomials.
Edited shader:

```
#version 450

#define EPSILON 1e-05
#define MAXITERATION 200

layout (binding = 0) uniform ParameterUBO {
    vec2 P_0, p1, p2, p3;
    int maxIndex, width, height, polynomSize, curveIndex;
} ubo;

layout(std140, binding = 1) readonly buffer CoefficientIn
{
    vec2 Coefficients[ ][6]; // buffer storing the coefficients of the polynomial.
};

layout(std140, binding = 2) buffer ParticleSSBOIn
{
    volatile vec4 approximation[][5]; // buffer storing the current approximations.
};

vec2 mul(const vec2 z, const vec2 zp) // complex multiplication
{
    vec2 result;
    result.x = z.x * zp.x - z.y * zp.y;
    result.y = z.y * zp.x + z.x * zp.y;
    return result;
}

vec2 div(const vec2 z, const vec2 zp) // complex division
{
    float bottom = zp.x * zp.x + zp.y * zp.y;
    vec2 result = mul(z, vec2(zp.x, -zp.y));

    return result / bottom;
}

vec2 f(const vec2 z, const in vec2[6] coeff) // compute polynom at z
{
    vec2 tmp = vec2(1, 0);
    vec2 result = coeff[0];
    for(uint i = 1; i < ubo.polynomSize; i++)
    {
        tmp = mul(tmp, z);
        result += mul(coeff[i], tmp);

    }
    return result;
}

vec2 fp(const vec2 z, const in vec2[6] coeff) // compute derivate at z.
{
    vec2 tmp = vec2(1, 0);
    vec2 result = coeff[1];
    for(uint i = 2; i < ubo.polynomSize; i++)
    {
        tmp = mul(tmp, z);
        result += mul(coeff[i] * float(i), tmp);
    }
    return result;
}

float absComplex(const vec2 z)
{
    return sqrt(z.x * z.x + z.y * z.y);
}

vec2 sumOfApproximation(const uint index, const in vec2[5] values)
{
    vec2 result = vec2(0);
    for(uint j = 0; j < ubo.polynomSize - 1; j++)
        if (j != index)
            result += div(vec2(1, 0), values[index] - values[j]) ;
    return result;
}


vec2[5] getApproximationsCase0(const uint indexGroup)
{
    vec2[5] result;
    for(uint i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        result[i] = approximation[indexGroup][i].xy;
    return result;
}

vec2[5] getApproximationsCase1(const uint indexGroup)
{
    vec2[5] result;
    for(uint i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        result[i] = approximation[indexGroup][i].zw;
    return result;
}

layout (local_size_x = 64, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

void main()
{
    uint index = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
    uint subIndex = index % (5);
    uint indexGroup = (index - subIndex) / (5);

    if(indexGroup < ubo.maxIndex)
    {
        bool switchCase = false;
        for(uint i = 0; i < MAXITERATION; i++)
        {
            const vec2[5] CurrentApproximation = switchCase? getApproximationsCase1(indexGroup) : getApproximationsCase0(indexGroup);
            const vec2 z = CurrentApproximation[subIndex];
            const vec2 p = f(z, Coefficients[indexGroup]);

            const vec2 pp = fp(z, Coefficients[indexGroup]);
            const vec2 POverPP = div(p, pp);
            const vec2 sum = sumOfApproximation(subIndex, CurrentApproximation);
            const vec2 zPlusOne = z - div(POverPP, vec2(1, 0) - mul(POverPP, sum));

            if(switchCase)
                approximation[indexGroup][subIndex].zw = zPlusOne;
            else
                approximation[indexGroup][subIndex].xy = zPlusOne;

            if(absComplex(z - zPlusOne) < EPSILON || absComplex(z) < EPSILON)
            {
                approximation[indexGroup][subIndex].xy = zPlusOne;
                break;
            }

            switchCase != switchCase;
        }
    }
}
```

A full exemple is avalable in [this](https://github.com/JulienGery/SDFBezier/tree/sandBox) repo.

I tried to:

- add a new buffer
- define the buffer as volatile
- make one step per call

but all this destroyed the performance.
Currently it can solve 2073600 different polynomials in 15ms on a 1050.

Edit:
After reviewing my post, I realize that it may be confusing. My original question was, 'How do I keep my 5 threads in sync?'
The 'approximation' buffer is filled with the starting points of the method.
Since my initial post, I have edited the shader and tested it on multiple hardware without any failures.
I discovered that I had been computing 414720 polynomials instead of the intended 2073600. Additionally, I noticed that abs(f(approximation)) is greater than 1e-05, due to the step being too small near roots, which may be a probleme.

Comment: Do you have a question about this?

Comment: How can I make it safe without compromising performance?

Comment: @julien Why is the performance of an unsafe solution of importance?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo. That's true, but I'm looking for a better solution. While I don't mind sacrificing some performance, I'm searching for the optimal solution. (It does work when they share the same cache and most of them are close to the answer.)

Comment: Have you worked out why it's unstable? The performance and the instability are somewhat orthogonal problems to solve. Is `approximation` zero initialized? Currently you use it in iteration zero, with whatever value it starts with?

Comment: Unstable = sumOfAproximation() iterating over values written by 5 threads, which may or may not be in the same warp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem you have is that you are trying to do cross-thread operations without any synchronization. Specifically ...

`sumOfAproximation()` is iterating over 5 values written by 5 different threads, and because 5 is not a multiple of the hardware subgroup (warp/wave) size you have no guarantee when those 5 threads are running relative to each other. Indeed, some of the 5 may not have even started running at the point the other threads in the set of 5 run.

If you want any guarantees of thread scheduling you MUST either:

(1) Ensure that all threads you care about are exchanging data are inside the same work group (in your current code that is 64 threads). You can then synchronize threads within the workgroup with barrier() operations (and possibly memoryBarrier() operations too) to ensure each thread has reached that point before continuing. Downside is that barriers can be slow. For best performance you want your workgroup size to be an integer multiple of the hardware subgroup size.

If you are sharing data inside the same workgroup you may then get some performance boost from using shared memory rather than global memory for the intermediate values, at least on desktop hardware.

(2) Ensure that all threads you care about are running inside the same hardware subgroup, and then use subgroup operations (`GL_KHR_shader_subgroup`) to exchange data as needed. This can be faster, as you avoid barriers, but the subgroup size is vendor specific so you may have to handle variability there.

(3) The other approach would to simply skip the cross-thread part of this and complete each group of 5 inside a single shader thread invocation, just as you would write the single threaded code for a CPU. If you can merge threads by a factor of 5 and still have a big enough problem space to fill the GPU with threads, then this may not be a major issue.

Comment: Yes, writing it as if it were single-threaded is a possibility (and might be better in fact).